# Why is this simple query taking a long time to execute and performing full table scan?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

simple query is taking long time around 630 sec to execute 
performing full table scan.
please help me to rewrite the query and also suggest me if any indexes need to add.

Query:

```
mysql> explain SELECT count(DISTINCT(tab1.idnum)) as totalresults FROM (`tab1`) LEFT JOIN `tab2` ON tab2.idnum = tab1.col1id WHERE tab1.userid = '165258' AND `result` = 'correct' AND tab2.department = 'DEPT1' AND tab2.book = 2096 AND `quarantined` = 0;
```

Explain Plan:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                      | key     | key_len | ref                       | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tab1 | ref    | userid,col1id,result,userid_status | userid  | 4       | const                     | 14720 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tab2 | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY | 4       | comp1.tab1.col1id |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table structutre:

```
mysql> show create table tab1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab1` (
  `idnum` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `questid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `col1id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `result` enum('correct','incorrect') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'def1',
  `answergiven` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` enum('calibrating','normal') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'def2',
  `quarantined` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnum`),
  KEY `questid` (`questid`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `col1id` (`col1id`),
  KEY `result` (`result`),
  KEY `userid_status` (`userid`,`status`),
  KEY `questid_status` (`questid`,`status`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=143018786 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table tab2\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab2
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab2` (
  `idnum` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestarted` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `timefinished` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `questionlist` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `topics` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `totalnum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `completednum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `assignment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `department` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `book` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cqs` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `metatype` varchar(25) DEFAULT 'topic',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnum`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `assignment` (`assignment`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13547403 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Rolled back to the last readable version. @pvr If you want to delete your question, delete it, but do not mask or obfuscate it.

Comment: @MattCalhoun: Which discussion with Shog9 do you refer to?

Comment: Hey @mafso! Sorry for the confusion, Matt can't comment here but he, I and pvr have been carrying on a conversation via flags mod-messages and email regarding some potential issues with this and a few other posts that contain information which pvr shouldn't have posted. As Matt understands the issue best, I advised him to redact the problematic data without invalidating the answers.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the reply. But... how should I see this in the review queue? That someone pretends that you think this is a good edit without providing a link or anything doesn't help at all. The only reason why I didn't reject (and flag) was because the other edits were approved, so there could be a reason. Looking at Matt's user site (to see if this looks like intentional vandalism or whatever), looking through the posts here etc took me quite some time. Looking back at it, none of the edits here should have been approved with the information given. I begin to understand robo-reviewers...

Comment: The edit comment exists to provide context for the change - the edit itself is what should determine approval or rejection, @mafso. In this case, most of the edits were careful to change only symbols without affecting the meaning of the posts being edited; one accidentally screwed up the formatting and was rejected. This sort of thing happens all the time, though usually by the asker (who in this case kinda shot himself in the foot by making some very bad edits at the start). If a more extensive set of changes had been needed, it'd probably have made more sense to coordinate this on meta.

Answer (score 1):

You need a multi-column index, ie. one that spans userid AND col1id in tab1 at the same time. Try:

```
create index idx_usr_col1 on tab1(userid,col1id)
```

Comment: if possible please rewrite my query.

Comment: did you try it? it's possible that you don't have to rewrite the query. what does EXPLAIN say? You might have to give mysql a hint to use the correct index, or you might update your index statistics which is the preferred way. The MySQL optimizer is relative to expensive databases AFAIK relatively dumb, but it should be able to handle *that* simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(distinct result.idnum)) as totalresults FROM `tab1` as result
inner join (select distinct idnum from `tab2` where department = 'DEPT1' and book = 2096 ) as col11 ON col11.idnum = result.col1id
 WHERE result.userid = '165258' AND `result` = 'correct'  AND `quarantined` = 0;
```

Comment: query is taking long time than my query

Comment: idnum is the auto-incrementing primary key, so EVERY value will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding multi-column indices for MySQL to use:

```
ALTER TABLE `tab2` ADD INDEX idx_col1id_userid_result_quarantined (`col1id`, `userid`, `result`, `quarantined`);

ALTER TABLE `tab1` ADD INDEX idx_department_book (`department`, `book`);
```